# Why are the dynamics on center manifold given by $u'=Au+f(u,h(u))$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am trying to wrap my head around the following theorem. In particular why equation 2.1.4 describes the dynamics of eq. 2.1.2. . Several books mention that there is a proof in Carr's book to which I unfortunately have no access.

Why is restricting the equation to the center manifold not given by:

$x'=Ax+f(x,x)$ and

$Dh(x)x'=h'(x)=y'=By+g(x,y)=Bh(x)+g(x,h(x))$

Why do we have $u'=Au+f(u,h(u))$ and not $u'=Bu+g(u,h(u))$, $u=h(x)$? Isn't the vector field $F(x,y):=(Ax+f(x,y),By+g(x,y))$ supposed to be along the cencter manifold, i.e. $F(x,h(x))$? What am I missing?

Many thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are the properties of $A$ and $B$? I'd expect that the eigenvalues of $B$ have all negative real part and that those of $A$ are non-negative and $A$ is allowed to have a null-space?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, I think that is the case. It is form the book by Wiggins.

Answer (score 0):

An answer is given on page 62 in https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/yanghong.huang/teaching/MATH4041/part4.pdf